# Why would Luke give away this piece of information?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

[image: Map]

<sup>[[Image Source]](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/force-awakens-big-data-management-tristan-bishop)</sup>

At the beginning of **[The Force Awakens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/)** we learn that **[Lor San Tekka](http://www.starwars.com/databank/lor-san-tekka)** somehow came into posession of the missing piece of the map that ultimately led to Rey to Luke Skywalker.

This [**Star Wars Wiki**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Map_to_Skywalker) article says:

> ... **Lor San Tekka was given a portion of the map by Skywalker.**
>
> <sup>[[Reference: "Star Wars: The Visual Encyclopedia"]](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Visual_Encyclopedia)</sup>

But to me this doesn't seem to fit with what we see in **[The Last Jedi](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2527336/)**, where we hear Luke say e.g.:

> *How did you find me?*
>
> *You think that I came to the most unfindable place in the galaxy for no reason at all?*
>
> *I came to this island to die.*
>
> ***I'm not coming back, nothing can change my mind.***

This doesn't sound like Luke ever wanted to be found, so why would he give away the location of his hiding place to anyone?

**My Question:**

- Why did Luke give the map to Lor San Tekka *(or is the Star Wars Wiki wrong)*?

Comment: There's a difference between *not coming back* and *not wanting to be found*.

Comment: I don't think this is a good enough explanation for an answer as it relies on speculation, but I assumed that Luke left the map with Lor San Tekka as a "call me in case of emergency" contingency, but his years (decades?) of meditation time on Ahch-To convinced him to not take part in galactic events ever again.

Comment: Luke isn't entirely consistent in his tries to abandon each and everyone either, some of it is just drama. As witnessed with his whole tree burning idea, abandoned as soon as Yoda did what he only *claimed* to be doing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Luke didn't give it to him, Lor San Tekka found it.

Speaking to Lor San Tekka at the beginning of *The Force Awakens*, Kylo Ren says:

> The map to Skywalker. We know **you found it.** And now you're going to
>   give it to the First Order.

Later, Kylo Ren is interrogating Rey, and says:

> [ The droid's ] carrying a section of a navigational chart. And we
>   have the rest. Recovered from the archives of the Empire... but we
>   need the last piece.

So Luke (or someone who figured out his destination) infiltrated the Empire's archives and "extracted" the important piece, which showed the location of Ahch-To. That person then hid the map piece, and eventually, Lor San Tekka tracked it down.

(the only reference I could find to Lor San Tekka in the Visual Encyclopedia is on page 67, where it describes Poe's search for the map, ending with Lor San Tekka - but it just says "San Tekka finally gives Luke's location to Poe")

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd biggest flaw in The Force Awakens is the precept that there would be a "map to Skywalker." Such a thing is absurd. You don't have a map to a person, you have a map to a location. This could have been easily fixed by changing the focus of the movie from the quest for Luke to the quest for the lost Jedi temple. Then the answer to your question becomes more tangible.

Maybe it's been a long time since the Jedi temple's location was known by anyone outside of the Jedi order (if ever). If the Empire spent time looking for it, then it would make sense that they had incomplete information, and that the rest of the information could be discovered, found, and/or given to someone by Luke. (Again, can we think of any possible explanation for the imperial archives having any information about Luke's whereabouts 30 years after the end of the Empire? No. It makes no sense.)

The real problem with Lor San Tekka is that we know almost nothing about him. We do know that he knew Leia and Ben Solo, and he considered her royalty, which means he was probably from Alderaan and a friend of Baal Organa. As such, chances are he knew Luke, and there is a chance Luke secured some of his knowledge about the Jedi Temple's location with this trusted ally. But, getting back to your question, why would Luke give that information to someone and then go there to hide out? The only answer I can think of is that they're not connected. He gave the information about the Jedi temple's location to Tekka at some earlier time (during the 30 year gap) for some other reason. Then, after the fiasco with Ben Solo, he decided to go hide in the most unfindable place in the galaxy--without thinking that anyone else would be able to find it.

Of course, this raises other questions. How does anyone know that Luke went to the lost Jedi temple? Why did they even need a full navigational chart? (If they had the last piece then they had the planet's coordinates, so why not just go there?) How did they know what part of the planet to go to? (Planet's are huge!) Etc. Etc.